# Is $ F(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_{(0,x)}f(t)dt $ Lebesgue integrable (assume that $f$ is integrable)?

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $f$ is a nonnegative and Lebesgue integrable function on $(0,+\infty)$. Is the following function $F(x)$ Lebesgue integrable on $(0,+\infty)$?
$$F(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_{(0,x)}f(t)dt,~ x>0$$

Comment: not in general, by example choose $f:=\chi_{(0,1)}$

Comment: Many thanks! @Masacroso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use Tonelli to compute that
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dtdx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{t}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x}dxf(t)dt,
\end{align*}
but
\begin{align*}
\int_{t}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x}dx=\infty.
\end{align*}
So you will end up with the integrand that $\infty\cdot f(t)$, so $f$ got to be $0$ a.e. in order to have the finite integral value, which is necessary zero.

Comment: @ user284331  Do you mean $F(x)$ can not be integrable if $f$ is not equal 0 a.e ?

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant, and the integral of $F$ is zero too.

Comment: Thanks! @user284331